# React: 'fix' scroll position in changing list of components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, scrollbar, lazy-loading

I am developing a simple text messenger with React. I have a component that displays messages. I have a custom hook that handles fetching the messages.

The problem I want to solve is that I want to be able to lazy load older messages only when a user scrolls up to see them. This is 'working', but I am having a lot of trouble persisting the 'scroll' state of the component between rerenders (caused by fetching the data).

**!!!important**

New messages are displayed at the bottom of the screen, lazily loaded messages are coming in at the top (think any modern text messenger). I am pretty sure this is the reason I am having issues in the first place.

**!!!**

The scroll behaviour I would like would be that the existing top message stays in the same position on the screen after the rerender, but the messages above would be rendered offscreen. What I get is the component immediately scrolling to the top upon rendering the new messages.

I imagine this is a solved problem, but I am struggling to figure out a straightforward/clean way to get this behavior.

I think the crux of my difficulty is that I need to append to the list from both directions. This behavior is quite natural for adding to the end of a list (this is what happened by default when sending new messages before I implemented a scroll feature), but in the case of loading old messages, I instead have to add to the beginning.

I considered and briefly tried separating my batches of messages into their own lists (providing me a list of lists that I could independently render). My implementation of this ended up feeling uglier and more unnatural than a single list and didn't directly solve the problem either.

A potential solution that I am going to try is to somehow invert the direction of the stack such that it constructs itself from the bottom up (direction=col-reverse and then reverse the list). I think this might happen to solve my problem, but it feels a bit hacky.

Here is the current container component jsx for displaying the messages:

```
  <Card sx={{ width: "95%", height: "90%" }}>
          <div style={{ overflowY: "scroll", height: "100%" }}>
            <Stack
              spacing={1}
              height={"100%"}
              alignItems={"flex-end"}
              justifyContent={"right"}
            >
              {fullyLoaded ? (
                <div style={{ height: "30vh" }}> no more stuff to load</div>
              ) : isFetching ? (
                <>currently fetching stuff</>
              ) : (

                <Button onClick={fetchMorePhrases}> fetch more stuff </Button>

              )}
              {awfulPhrases.map((awfulPhrase) => {
                return (
                  <Message
                    contextUser={contextUser}
                    message={awfulPhrase}
                    conversationUsers={conversationUsers}
                  />
                );
              })}
              <div ref={bottomEl}></div>
            </Stack>
          </div>
        </Card>
```

I don't think that the implementation details of the hook are that important, but `awfulPhrases` is a state that contains a chronologically ordered list (oldest first) of messages sent in the conversation. This can be updated by the `fetchMorePhrases` function or by the subscription which is listening for new messages in the conversation.

The reason why the list is currently ordered in this direction is that I didn't want to have to do the 'expensive' operation of appending to the front of the list every time a message comes through. Thinking about it now I do wonder if `setAwfulPhrases([...awfulPhrases,newPhrase])` even gets optimized...